# How to achieve nullable enums?

Tags: springdoc

I'm struggling with generating an API doc that has nullable enums in it.

### Setup

We have an endpoint that accepts a request, this requests contains a field of enum type which is nullable. So imagine something like this:

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/count-colors")
public Integer countColors(@Parameter(description = "Request object", required = true)
                           @RequestBody Request request) {
  return 1;
}

class Request {
  @Nullable
  @Schema(nullable = true, example = "RED")
  private Color color;
}

enum Color {
  RED,
  GREEN,
  YELLOW
}
```

Once we use springdoc-openapi to generate the swagger api definitions we get back the following yml:

```yaml
[...]
components:
  schemas:
    Request:
      type: object
      properties:
        color:
          type: string
          nullable: true
          example: RED
          enum:
          - RED
          - GREEN
          - YELLOW # missing entry for null
```

This allows the request to omit the color property, but if anyone sends a color = null, this is not a valid request according to the api, because null is not listed as a value in the enum.

I'm using springdoc-openapi version 1.6.11.

### Question

Because annotations like @NotNull are also picked up, I would expect @Nullable to be picked up as well and therefore null should be added to the list of possible values. Or how can I achieve an enum that allows null as a valid input?

Any help is much appreciated.

#### Other infos

I already tried to find a workaround but did not succeed. I tried adding null to the allowableValues in the Schema annotation, but that is not allowed as the error attribute value must be constant error pops up.

Possibly connected to this GitHub issue: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3945

Edit:

- 26.10.2022: added post endpoint example to show how I use the request class.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a query parameter of the GET method?
If the query parameter is of the form `color=null`, null is recognized as a string, so it throws an IllegalArgumentException(No enum constant) to find the null value from the Enum.

A value of the form `color=` will be treated as null.
example `curl "http://localhost:8080/hello?color="`

This is the code I tried.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("hello")
public class HelloController {
  @GetMapping
  public String index(@Nullable @Schema(nullable = true, example = "RED") Color color) {
    System.out.println(color); // null
    return "Hello";
  }
}
```

---

27.10.2022: added post endpoint

The post endpoint is also set to null.

```java
  @PostMapping
  public String post(@Parameter(description = "Request object", required = true)
                       @RequestBody EnumClassRequest request) {
    System.out.println(request.getColor());
    return "Hello";
  }

public class EnumClassRequest {
  @Nullable
  @Schema(nullable = true, example = "RED")
  private Color color;

  public EnumClassRequest(@JsonProperty("color") Color color) {
    this.color = color;
  }

  public Color getColor() {
    return color;
  }
}
```

```bash
$ curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/enum" -d '{ "color": null }'  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
Hello
```

[image]

---

27.10.2022: added null to enum

I was able to add null to the possible values list by utilizing the enum's toString.

```java
public enum Color {
  RED("RED"),
  GREEN("GREEN"),
  YELLOW("YELLOW"),
  NULL(null);

  String name;

  Color(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

I can add null to the list of possible values in yaml as well.

```yaml
    EnumClassRequest:
      type: object
      properties:
        color:
          type: string
          nullable: true
          example: RED
          enum:
          - RED
          - GREEN
          - YELLOW
          - null
      description: Request object
```

But swagger-ui doesn't show null.

[image]

Comment: In my case it's a DTO that is sent as the body of a post request. I added an example to the question.

Comment: @phyratokar I added the post endpoint, so please check it.

Comment: Thanks for the update YutaSaito, but I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing. Your code seems to show that spring controller is accepting a request object with null as the enum value. But my problem is that the generated API doc does not specify null as a valid value.
Could you check that the swagger doc generated from your code contains both the nullable: true and the null in the possible enum values array?

Comment: sorry. I had a misunderstanding.  
But I don't think it is necessary to add null to the list of possible values.  
Because everyone knows that if there is nullable, null will be entered.  

But if you want to add null to the list of possible values, you can do it by adding null to allowableValues as you describe.

```
  @Nullable
  @Schema(nullable = true, example = "RED", allowableValues = { "null" })
  private Color color;
```

What do you mean by not allowed below?

> but that is not allowed as the error attribute value must be constant error pops up.

Comment: We are using a middleware that does request validation for us, based on the swagger definitions. So yes we need null to be present in the enum values array as otherwise it's not allowed to send null as the value.
allowableValues = "null" adds the string "null" as a valid value, not actual null, so that does not help. Then adding allowableValues = null does not work as java does not compile because null cannot be used in a annotation. Error "attribute value must be constant error".

Comment: Thank you.
I added it again, so please check it.

Comment: You are right, like this the swagger API generation adds the null value to the enum array correctly. But this is a change in the code and not only in how the API is generated. I mean now the enum is nullable and has a specific null value. Unfortunately I cannot use this for our code as it prevents any usage of the enum that is not nullable for example.